# Category of Non-Negative Integers and Addition

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, monoid

Following is my attempt to construct a category and some questions:

Consider the set of integers $\Bbb{Z}$ as objects.

- There is a morphism $A \to B$ if there exists some number $c$ such that $A + c = B$. Henceforth denoted $A \xrightarrow{c} B$
- There is an identity where $c = 0$.
- Morphisms can be composed. $A \xrightarrow{a} B \xrightarrow{b} C = A \xrightarrow{a+b} C$.
- e.g. $1 \xrightarrow{1} 2 \xrightarrow{2} 4 =  1 \xrightarrow{3} 4$
- This composition is associative. The composition is just addition of differences, and addition is associative.
  Ex. $1 \xrightarrow{1} 2 \xrightarrow{2} 4 \xrightarrow{3} 7 == 1 \xrightarrow{1 + (2 + 3)} 7 == 1 \xrightarrow{(1 + 2) + 3} 7$
- Composition with the identity, $(c + 0) = c$, follows trivially from the definition of zero and addition.

From the above characteristics, it follows that
$A + c = B$ is a category.

Observation:
On $\Bbb{Z}$, there is a morphism between every ob and every other ob, since $c = B - A$ and $x - y$ is an integer for all integer input.

Consider the above defintion, but instead on $\Bbb{Z}^*$ (non-negative integers).
The defining characteristics of the category still hold true, but the observation does not.
There is no morphism from $2$ to $1$, as $c$ would need to be $-1$, not contained in $\Bbb{Z}^*$.
Specifically, there are morphisms where $A \leqslant B$.

Consider the same definition, but on $\Bbb{Z}^+$ (positive integers). This is the same set as $\Bbb{Z}^*$, but without zero.
Observe that this definition does not constitute a category. Specifically, there is no identity, as for a morphism $A \xrightarrow{c} A$ to exist, $c$ must equal zero.

Questions:

- Did I make any mistakes above?
- One source of confusion for me is the difference between this category and a monoid. The examples I described as categories are clearly monoids, and indeed non-negative integers with addition is wikipedia's example of a monoid. However, it adds this confusing (to me) line, saying "More generally, in category theory, the morphisms of an object to itself form a monoid, and, conversely, a monoid may be viewed as a category with a single object".
- It seems to me that there's an infinite number of objects as I've defined my category. Is there some other category that wikipedia is talking about, or am I misunderstanding something in my definition of objects in this category?

Comment: Welcome! I can follow what you've written, and it looks fine to me! Nice work. Monoids come up a lot in category theory, in various ways. The defn Wikipedia has in mind is "let $M$ be some monoid. Define a category $\mathcal C_M$ with a single object $\ast$, with a morphism $f_m: \ast \to \ast$ for each $m \in M$, and composition defined by $f_{m}f_{m'} = f_{mm'}$." This construction is nice, because it also goes the other way - every one-object category gives rise to a monoid. In fact it's an equivalence of categories between the category of monoids and the category of one-object categories.

Comment: On all integers, I observed that there is a morphism between every integer and every other. Do we call that well-connected, like in graph theory?
For non-negative integers, I noted that it isn't well connected.

Comment: There is some category theory jargon for what you've come up with: you've observed that monoids come with a [natural preorder](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2463279/473276), and constructed the [preorder category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/preorder#AsACategory) corresponding to that preorder. In the case of a commutative cancellative monoid, that preorder is actually a partial order.

Comment: I don't think that this is a preorder in general. The c is the morphism, not just that it exists. For non-cancellative monoids, the category won't be thin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A smaller example might be useful to address your questions.
Let $M = \{1,a,b\}$ be the monoid with identity $1$ defined by $aa = ba = a$ and $bb = ab = b$. There are several ways to associate a category to $M$. The first way is similar to your construction. You take $M$ as set of objects and the morphisms are of the form $x \xrightarrow{r}y$ where $xr = y$. For $M$, you get the category pictured below:

$\hskip 100pt$[image]

About the "confusing line" *the morphisms of an object to itself form a monoid*. The morphisms from $1$ to $1$ form the monoid $\{1\}$, the morphisms from $a$ to $a$ form the monoid $\{1, a\}$ and the morphisms from $b$ to $b$ form the monoid $\{1, b\}$.

A second way is to associate a category to $M$ is suggested in the second part of  the "confusing line". It consists to take the one object category represented below:

$\hskip 160pt$[image]